# consecutive days problem

Tags: support, consecutive-days

I have a problem with my conseutive days counter. I visited the site every day in the last two months. Yesterday the counter showed 62 consecutive days. Today I see 2 consecutive days on my profile page. How can be this possible?

Comment: Have you visited every day, local time, or every GMT day? The days are based on GMT, not local time

Comment: Have you clicked on "2 consecutive days"? It will open a calendar with green background on days you visited the site.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure there was no more than 24 hours gap between your logins/visits?

Consecutive days are calculated on the basic of GMT days, so if you don't measure time in GMT, it's safe to assume that day is each subsequent 24 hours period.

On the margin, it would be more fair, it the algorithm would measure the time gap between logins/visits.

Comment: Strictly speaking it's UTC rather than GMT, but your answer is essentially correct.

Comment: I think there was a 24 hour gap between two visits. I visited the site saturday morning and sunday evening. It should be 2 days in GMT too. (Hungary use GMT+1). I had a bad feeling about that 24 hour gap and I've checked my profile yesterday. It showed me 62 days. It was 15 hours ago, I've made a few reviews at that time too.
By the way: The missing day is saturday.

Comment: @gkovacs90 It's summer time, so Hungary is at GMT+2. A day is between 2am and 2am.

Comment: Worth noting that simply loading the front page or your profile doesn't necessarily constitute a visit - the Enthusiast and Fanatic badges require that you spend a _little_ time for the day's activity to be counted. Not saying that's what happened in _this_ case, but it's worth knowing in general when it comes to the topic.